# R cov(x) where x is data.frame with one row

Tags: r, statistics, dataframe, covariance

I need to calculate covariance on a data.frame but i get matrix of NaN if the data.frame has only one row.
What should I do for covariance on data.frame with one row?

Well the main problem is:
i have an observation from normal distribution( yeah sometimes it too small )
i want to calculate mean and covariance matrix to maximise Likelihood function

if there is only one observation is it possible?

Comment: To take the covariance of a data frame with one row does not make sense, because covariance is defined to be between two or more sets of data. Why do you want to take the covariance of one row?

Comment: i wanted covatiance vector with itself

Comment: That is the same as variance. Try taking the variance of the vector instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excerpt from `?cov`

```
The denominator n - 1 is used which gives an unbiased estimator of
the (co)variance for i.i.d. observations.  These functions return
‘NA’ when there is only one observation (whereas S-PLUS has been
returning ‘NaN’), and fail if ‘x’ has length zero.
```

If you need to divide by `n` instead of `n-1`, I recommend writing a special covariance function.

Comment: is there any build in ones or its too rare to have one observation
in my program a change some constant to avoid data.frames with one row

Comment: You could test for a single observation and if TRUE, build a zeroed matrix.

Comment: zeroed is bad cause it can not be covariance matrix of gause distribution
if you keen on maching learning and probabilities what would you suggest to do with matrix of single obseervation
may be i should calculate covariance with n as denominator when i have only one observation

Comment: hm. I might be wrong, but wouldn't the variance of a single observation be 0? I think maybe the solution is to handle single observation cases entirely differently, depending on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a single observation, covariance is not defined. A matrix of `NaN` is therefore perfectly reasonable output.

As to how best to handle this in the context of your problem, it's impossible to say without knowing more about your problem.

Comment: may be i missunderstand something from statistic course but is covariance can be defined in math for one vector?

Comment: @YaroslavKishchenko: That's a different matter: `var(c(1,2,3,4))`.

Comment: what difference between var and cov
my obsservations are from multivariate distribution

Comment: @YaroslavKishchenko If `x` is a vector then `var(x) = cov(x,x)`

Comment: @ChrisTaylor @NPE His vector `x` is a single multivariate observation. `var(x)`, as in the variance of `length(x)` values, does not seem to be the solution he is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, do the following:

Check if the data frame only has one row. If it has one row, find the variance by using the `var` function in R instead of the `cov` function.  If it has more than one row, use `cov`.

Note that the covariance of a vector with itself is the same as the variance of that vector.

Comment: thanks now i get but one little question to make it clear
i never met before covar function I am using cov
are they same?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. The `cov` function is the correct to use for covariance (there is no function called `covar`, I remembered wrongly).

Comment: @YaroslavKishchenko Is this really what you want? I thought your vector was actually a single multivariate observation. The variance of the collection of elements from the single multivariate observation is not the same as the variance of the multivariate observation. It seems like you want these special cases to have a 0 filled covariance matrix.

Comment: @ndoogan yaeh you right after a some coding i got that it is not i wanted, i only got one number instead of matrix